# Twitter Bootstrap: Printing a Badge

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I'm trying to print a badge from twitter bootstrap.

Have a look at [this small example](http://jsfiddle.net/aaj45/). On the left is a simple badge which displays the number '4':

`<span class="badge badge-warning">4</span>`

and on the right is the Twitter Bootstrap css file without the "@media print" statements, which disable background-colors for printings. If you try to print this page (print preview) the badge has lost its color. How can I make the badge visible on printings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable "Print Background colors and images" in your browser...

Chrome - tick checkbox bottom-left of print preview.

IE - click Setup (cogs icon, top-left) then tick checkbox (left-middle of popup window)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution provided by buffjape requires browser-specific action, which no developer likes to rely upon.

Alternatively, You could **add a border to the badge**. It retains the badge's shape and real estate, and uses less ink/toner (since it's a border and not a fill).

Assuming you are working with default badge CSS values, add this to your CSS:

```
@media print {
  .badge {
    padding: 2px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
}
```

The `padding` line reduces the default value by 1px on all sides, allowing the look of the badge to remain unchanged; i.e. if you had a "print preview" of the page with the badge, the user would still see the badge as normal.

The default `#ddd` color looks pretty washed out on a standard B/W laser printer, so I tend to shift all coloration to black when printing. Adjust as needed.